Good TV shows for teen that promote good values
My teen's teachers are complaining that he talks and act a bit too much like the current celebrity youtubers.
Are there still any good TV shows suitable for teenagers, with reasonable social interactions between teens, that will still captivate this generation that don't want TV anymore?

You don't need to look to TV for this - there are numerous youtubers who are fun, educational, and provide positive role models. See everyday astronaut, smarter every day, and others like them for example.

Some educational channels I can remember off the top of my head if your kids are interested in STEM: Vsauce, veritasium are some good general science-related channels (Mostly about psychology, mathematics, and astronomy). Computerphile, fireship, freecodecamp, low level learning, coderized, are a few good channels for programming. Mark Rober: Mostly about engineering fun and interesting stuff. The channel owner is an ex-NASA engineer (Mark Rober himself).

All great channels, but no social interactions reference.
Additionally, I have no way to force him to watch a specific youtube channel. Youtube does an excellent job at pushing back to the questionable social behavior channels. Additionally, Google has a spat with the local gov, so they turned off child accounts in the region. TV is probably the only.

And please note that we have an international user base. You may rethink your question considering that based on your user profile you probably don’t want advice from India, France, Simbabwe…. You get the gist.

Can you clarify what behaviors are considered problematic and what you have tried already? Also, how old is your child? You indicated they're a teen, but you used the pre-teen tag.

Age is 13. Since the question in English any TV Series available in English is welcome. If there are worthy shows in India or French with subtitles are welcome too.

Steeven He is exaggerating it a bit for humor, but it's more or less what's happening in classes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfJ-oDzEvLg . Please remember, this is a generation that was trapped at home during covid. They did not have a conventional upbringing with "True" physical social interactions.

Can you clarify what you mean by 'reasonable social interactions between teens?' It's very broad and I'm not sure what you consider 'reasonable'. Additionally, what social interactions you're referencing is equally vague; at that age, children start dating, they might start focusing on their friends more, they might start doing a regular job. Perhaps you have an idea what are reasonable social interactions that are substantially different from my own.

Ok. Let's put some specifics. It has to pass the rating for 12yo from it's county of origin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_picture_content_rating_system

I’ve got some recommendations! You weren’t super specific with genre, so I included shows I’ve watched all of and enjoyed, either alongside teens (who also enjoyed it) or as a teen myself.
From Netflix:
One Day at a Time — Live action, family-based. I thought it was fun, but may be a bit boring if it’s not the kind of show your kid is into? Figured I’d present it as an option either way!
Bee and Puppycat — Animated, teen/young adult sci-fi/fantasy. Themes of growing up, dealing with change, and a pinch of loss/grief, all while still being whimsical and fun enough to leave you wanting more. I loved this show as a teen and still love it now! I rewatch it every year or so, it sparks joy. :)
Dead End: Paranormal Park — Animated, teen coming-of-age with a supernatural/mystery twist! Themes of identity, growing up, and found family. I watched (then later rewatched) the whole thing and had a grand time.
Young Sheldon — live action, lighthearted family-based fun. Kids, tweens, and teens interacting. There’s more seasons of it available on HBO Max if you finish the Netflix episodes!
From Disney+:
Gravity Falls - tween/teen coming-of-age with, you guessed it, a fantasy/supernatural/mystery twist! I absolutely loved this show as a tween/teen and still hold fond memories of it. Themes of identity, belonging, growing up, found family, and community. Full disclosure: sometimes things get dark (mostly during Weirdmageddon, which has a post-apocalyptic setting), but it’s brimming with wholesome content as well.
Toeing the line here with TV-14 rated Netflix shows:
The Good Place I think is a good option— even though it’s not about teenagers, it’s young adults exploring the ideas of morality and the concepts of heaven (the good place) and hell (the bad place). It teaches that “good” and “bad” people can both make mistakes and do bad things, but the real difference between them lies in whether they’re willing to reflect on their actions and be better people moving forward.
Brooklyn Nine-Nine is also… not teens, but young adults, interacting in a positive work environment. One of my favorite shows! Can show him that doing a job well can still be fun, as long as you know when to be serious.
Closing thoughts:
If your kid doesn’t like any of these, (honestly, I’m having trouble picturing a successful scenario where you convince a teenage boy to watch a show his parent has told him to watch) then you should ask him about the content he enjoys and what he likes about it. That would help you find content/shows you approve of that he’ll still get to have fun watching. Happy hunting!

I'd consider adding Steven Universe to that list.  While it's arguable targeting a slightly younger demographic it can easily be enjoyed by teens and adults.
It's noteworthy for tackling quite a few subjects - in some cases indirectly by analogy - that children and teens don't get from other media but really could benefit from learning.  Such as dealing with feelings of inadequacy or not living up to other's expectations, self doubts, relationships and even the perils of abusive relationships, the importance of consent, and refusing to have any character be controlled by gender norms etc.  The only problem is that the deeper stuff doesn't really start happening until the very end of season 1 so the first season does seem like a less mature monster of the week show that may loose a teens interest before it shows any more depth.
I believe Hulu has Steven Universe.
